# how to take a random element from existing array and then dont take it again?

Tags: java, file-io, random, arrays

I am asked to make a file of bytes.
I was given the array **byte a[] = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102}**
and now i must create the byte file out of the a[] array.
But i have limitations:

1. the data of the file must be random (from the a[])
2. all the bytes must be detected in the file almost the same times.

   public class WriteByteFile {
   byte[] a = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102};

   final String file = "file";

   /* open file */
   BufferedOutputStream out = null;
   try {
       out = new BufferedOutputStream
               (new BufferedOutputStream(file));
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
           System.err.println("Cannot open file : " + file1
               + ": " + e1.getMessage());
           System.exit(1);
       }

   /* write file */
   try {
       for (int b = 0; b < 1650; b++) {
           out.write(//here i must get the random element from a[]
                                    but not have it again for the next 5 times);
       }

Comment: I have no idea what this means; `all the bytes must be detected in the file almost the same times.`

Comment: Couldn't you just put the Bytes into an Array, then remove the element when you select it, and then reset the array once all the list is empty?

Comment: If the array is random how can it be set as well?

Comment: Maybe you should either refine your description or ask for better requirements.

Comment: the array itself is not random, but the selection of the array must be random. which means random elements from the a[] array, a defined array.

Comment: the second recomendation seems quite close to my original idea. I will work on that , although i am a little concerned about my whole code and its performance.

Answer (score 1):

`1.the data of the file must be random (from the a[])`

`2.all the bytes must be detected in the file almost the same times.`

These two lines are contradictory. If all characters has to be present `same no of times` in your file, then your selection of character from array is not random.

Comment: the data of the file must come from the a[] array. but be put in the file at random  selection.

Answer (score 0):

> all the bytes must be detected in the file almost the same times.

The key here is "almost". Exact equivalence is not required here, only statistical equivalence.

You will satisfy this if you pick each byte at random, independently on the others. The statistics will do the rest. If you keep throwing dice, you'll get 1-6 almost the same number of times, but there is no mechanism to guarantee exact equivalence (in fact, exact equivalence is quite unlikely here).

Comment: If i can reassure that the statistics itself will help me , then the random selection probably will be enough

Comment: @inspired_director then roll 1650 random dice and observe the results. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1650d6 and click `roll again` a few times.